# Обобщающее слово употреблено дважды

Tags: пунктуация

1. Если обобщающее слово, в целях усиления его смысловой роли при большом числе однородных членов предложения, употреблено дважды – перед перечислением и после него, то сохраняется принятая для конструкций с однородными членами и обобщающим словом пунктуация, т. е. двоеточие перед однородными членами и тире после них: Всё: быстро проехавший экипаж по улице, напоминание об обеде, вопрос девушки о платье, которое надо приготовить; ещё хуже, слово неискренного, слабого участия – всё болезненно раздражало рану, казалось оскорблением (Л.Т.); Мне было охота почитать про всё: и про травы, и про моря, и про солнце и звёзды, и про великих людей, и про революцию – про всё то, что люди хорошо знают, а я ещё не знаю (Пауст.).

Но у Гоголя:

> Всё это: шум, говор и толпа людей, – всё это было как-то чудно Акакию Акакиевичу.

есть еще и запятая перед тире. Почему?

Answer (score 4):

Кажется, нашла объяснение:http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-060.htm

В XIX в. и в начале XX в. очень часто (без строго определенных условий) употреблялись запятая и тире в качестве единого знака препинания. Особенно распространен был этот знак на стыке частей сложного предложения, как союзного, так и бессоюзного. 
У Гоголя, правда, не сложное, но осложнённое,ему надо было отделить части предложения друг от друга, усилить значимость того, что происходило вокруг Акакия Акакиевича, надевшего новую шинель :Всё это: шум, говор и толпа людей, – всё это было как-то чудно Акакию Акакиевичу. Вспомним содержание: до шинели он этого ничего не видел, был углублён в одну каллиграфию, людей не видел, а теперь увидел, жизнь обрела новый смысл. Гоголю нужен был усиленный знак, вот он и употребил запятую вместе с тире.

Comment: Похоже... 
И именно что "надо было отделить". Это к вопросу о том, что об эту запятую спотыкаешься.

Answer (score 3):

Да, вы правы. При таком употреблении обобщающих слов пунктуация сохраняется: ставится двоеточие после первого и тире перед вторым обобщающим словом. Запятая при однородных членах относится к разделяющим знакам препинания, поэтому ставится между ними, а не после.

О Гоголе и цитировании. У Гоголя запятая вполне может стоять, ведь правил  в редакции 1956 года тогда не было? ))).  Я считаю, что если цитировать надо с соблюдением авторской пунктуации. А если как-то не совпадает с современными нормами, то и не нужно брать цитату в учебники и пособия, есть много   других.

Comment: @Ларf, по поводу авторской пунктуации вынужден возразить. Полностью применить пунктуацию классиков просто невозможно. Отличия от современной, может, и не так бросаются в глаза, как в отношении орфографии (в узком смысле), но на большом объеме текста весьма заметны - и делают текст малочитабельным.
У большинства редакторов-корректоров реализуется идея, что "авторская" пунктуация сохраняется в том и том только случае, если она отступает от действовавших на момент написания или первого издания правил. Т.е. когда пунктуация действительно *авторская*, в исходном смысле слова.

Comment: Кстати о правилах... При  Гоголе вообще не существовало сколько-нибудь общепризнанных единых правил. Первая попытка что-то такое создать была предпринята Гротом в работе "Спорные вопросы русского правописания...", вышедшей в 1873 г. (если не наврал). Только в 80-х годах Грота стали признавать за эталон (да и то не везде и не все).

Answer (score 0):

У Гоголя не одно слово, тут тянет на едва ли не на два повторяющихся однородных члена, причем распространённых.
А вообще повторюсь. Этот момент - встреча запятой и тире - весьма туманно изложен в источниках, включая собственно правила. При желании можно найти доводы и за и против запятой едва ли не в любой фразе, что наверняка сейчас и сделают. Хотя у Гоголя запятая действительно напрашивается даже по интонации.

Я посмотрел источники... Едва ли не в половине всяких методичек и пособий запятой нет. Хотя у Гоголя она есть точно...

Comment: А мне не показалось, что запятая у Гоголя напрашивается. Наоборот, я об неё спотыкаюсь. А насчёт распространённых однородных членов, так тут Гоголю (в данных примерах) далеко и до Толстого, и до Паустовского.

Comment: В каком смысле далеко? По времени?  
А мне как раз и нравится, что об эту запятую спотыкаешься. У меня там интонационная (логическая?) пауза...